# How to add jquery knob in div tag in html

Tags: jquery-knob

```
I have the below index.html code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Myapp</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="Myapp" ng-controller="GameController">
<div>
            <div class="guessLeft">{{guesses}}</div>
            <div class="incorrectGuess">InCorrect guesses : <span ng-repeat="letter in incorrectlyChoosen">{{letter}}</span></div>
            <div class="correctGuess">Correct guesses :  <span ng-repeat="letter in correctlyChoosen">{{letter}}</span>
</div>
        <div class="youhavetoGuess">Your have to guess :  {{displayWord}}</div>
        <div class="takeInput">
            <input type="text" name="guess" ng-model="input.letter">
            <button ng-click="letterChoosen()">Submit</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

in the below div class
<div class="guessLeft">{{guesses}}</div>
```

I want to use jquery knob where I would show my guess count, that would start from 6 till 0.

what should I do to achieve this? any reference would help.

Comment: Can you share your controller part also, so that its better to suggest any option. Here in the plunker also you can update the sample:
https://plnkr.co/edit/nVCmukG5abpi1Y4ZHkrq?p=preview

Comment: Actually, I researched a bit and was able to apply jquery knob, below is the code for same, adding scripts under head
<script src="jquery-knob.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(function() {
        $(".dial").knob({
        'min':0,
    'max':6,
    fgColor: '#008CBA',
    'readOnly':true 

        }).trigger('change');
    });

</script>

Comment: I suggest the [roundSlider](http://roundsliderui.com) plugin which is easy to customize, also supports the angular directive support so you can use the two way binding also.
https://plnkr.co/edit/4QCig2?p=preview